# Send information from dismissing ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I got 2 views in my app. view1 present view2. I can do it throught `presentModalViewController` or like this : `self.navigationController pushViewController` it dosent matter.

I need to select some row in view2 and then go to view1 with some information. How can i do it without singeltones and global variables?

Comment: This Post might be interesting for you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.You can use the NSUserDefaults

Answer (score 2):

You can post a notification using NSNotificationCenter. Then you'll use the NSDictionary *infos to pass your data.

[NSNotificationCenter reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)